# Strapi is not loading the Collections from existing MongoDB hosted on Digital Ocean

Tags: javascript, mongodb, digital-ocean, strapi

I am creating a New Application using Strapi and I have tried to connect it with my MongoDB which is hosted on Digital Ocean but unfortunately **Strapi is not able to fetch the collections from existing MongoDB**. Here, I am mentioning the complete steps that I have followed to achieve the connection of Strapi with the existing MongoDB:

- I have followed this guide step by step to create a Strapi Application:  [Quick_Start_Strapi](https://strapi.io/documentation/getting-started/quick-start.html)
- Although, I need to connect to my existing MongoDB which is hosted on Digital Ocean. So, as per Strapi documentaion, I have mentioned all the credentials ( **host**, **port**, **username**, **password** ) of my existing Database only on the creation of the Strapi Application.
- In the last, when application is created successfully, I have switched my current directory to project directory and run the command:

  ```
  $ strapi start
  ```
- I haven't faced any error in the terminal , consequently, that means

  > The connection is successful
- Then, I have registered myself through Strapi Register Panel.
- After logging into the application, there is only one collection is shown on the Strapi Dashboard that is the "**Users Collection**". **Strapi failed to load any collection from existing MongoDB. In terms of Strapi, it failed to load any Content-Types.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to get all the already created collection from **mongodb**, you have to first add `content-types`.

Goto http://localhost:1337/admin and follow these steps ( after login )-

1. First add a `Content Type`

[image]

2. In `Advance Section`, add your collection name. It should be the same as in the database.( In the `Base Section` you can give any name to this collection)

[image]

3. Make sure to add all of the fields with correct field-types

[image]

4. Now just click on your collection under `Content Types` and you will get all of the records from the database.

[image]

I have created both of these records from `mongo shell` and they are showing in this section.

[image]

I am sure you get your answer

For more, check these links below-

[Strapi-Create-product](https://strapi.io/documentation/getting-started/quick-start.html#create-a-product)

You can see also official [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMl5IcFHA74)

Comment: is this still the only way to "recover" data from an existing MongoDB?