# Use existing schema of existing DB in strapi

Tags: strapi

I have created a strapi project and connected to existing database.
which has 3 schemas, namely:
public,
rivulet, and
prod
But I want to create new tables and all in the existing rivulet schema.
But right now it is now not creating the tables in any schema but creating in the DB itself.
Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to connect an existing database with Strapi CMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62656356/is-it-possible-to-connect-an-existing-database-with-strapi-cms)

Comment: Yes, thank you. @danbtl